# How Do I Stream Audio Into An Android Device?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, streaming

I need to play a sound received wirelessly (Bluetooth or Wi-Fi) from a device (Android, iPhone, PC, ETC) to an Android device (Running Android JB 4.2.2), i think it will be almost impossible using bluetooth because the replacement of BlueZ with Bluedroid (which does not support A2DP Sink profile).

How can i connect both devices and make the streaming?

Have anyone a project like that, or have a link where it's something similar?

Please help me find out how to do it, thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Alljoyn uses multiple transport layer and has many core services for data transfer between devices, it claims support for bluetooth but as now bluedroid is available, alljoyn can help you out with wi-fi, go through [alljoyn audio service](https://www.alljoyn.org/about/core-services/audio)

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will check it out and see what can i do with it.